# SVG -- Replacement for Flash application

Tags: flash, svg, raphael

We are currently looking at developing flash based applications (using Flex) in a web application. We are now leaning towards to use SVG [rapheljs](http://raphaeljs.com/) for developing this components. The questions are:

1. Is still SVG platform is widely adopted by browsers (without any plug-ins) are at least down the line of 8-10 months, any adoption is expected by browsers? Cross-browser support is god for us.
2. Is SVG can replace for a small time animation based programming instead of Flash

Any comments will be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Isn't the whole point of RaphaelJS that you don't *need* SVG support everywhere?

Comment: @Ken: Let me give you some more details, the whole point is using RaphaelJS is to develop such applications like flickr.com/map or google map, I have to choose either flash component running in browser or a sophisticated svg/vml based frameowork to solve this problem. I would like know whether any issues such as browser not supported, version conflicts, performance issues, memory problems etc., will come as bottlenecks if i use RaphaelJs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

raphaeljs will give you amazingly good crossbrowser support. I tried nearly a year ago and almost all the demos worked flawlessly (although a little slow) in IE 6.

I would never count on native SVG support by IE. But raphael bridges this gap, so actually you are good to go.

However, you should consider that flash often provides lower size, better performance and absolutely identical experience accross browsers. On the other hand it performs quite poorly on both Mac and Linux (doesn't necessarily mean it performs worse than alternatives).

Also, flex is a full grown framework including databinding, remoting, a skinnable gui component set, accessibility and many many other things.

If you're going to choose JS+DOM+SVG/VML/canvas do yourself a favour not to reinvent the wheel, but use a proper framework instead, such as [qooxdoo](http://qooxdoo.org/).

Comment: As someone who has had to debug Flash content, I can say it absolutely does not provide "identical experience across browsers".  It doesn't even provide an identical experience with different minor versions of the Flash plugin on the same browser.  (That's why versions exist: because they changed something.)  IE doesn't even use the same plugin binary as other browsers, so double your test matrix again.  It might be more consistent than RaphaelJS today -- I don't know -- but it's pretty far from perfect.

Comment: The chances of running into an issue between different versions or combinations of Flash/browsers is pretty small.  Especially when you compare with JS/HTML and all the different browsers. If you're getting the same volume and severity of differences between minor versions of flash, or even different browsers, as you would with HTML/JS, you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of defense that is: I'm not having any problems, so if you are, "you're probably doing something wrong".  There's no technology you *can't* say that about!  If Flash crashes my browser daily, am I doing something wrong?  All I use it for is watching Youtube videos.  Maybe I'm clicking too hard?

Comment: BTW, the comparison is not Flash and HTML/JS -- it's Flash and RaphaelJS.  And I can't remember the last time I saw any differences in VML implementations across browser versions: it's like MSFT created it and then never updated it.  Raw SVG is less consistently supported, but that's the point of RaphaelJS.